# Python: DNS Query: Pydns? Dig? Socket?

Tags: python, command-line, dns

I am trying to write a python script that will take in a series of command line arguments of hostnames and perform a dns query. If the query is successful nothing will happen, else, an exception will be thrown. Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

   import socket
   import sys, os
   import DNS

   if len(sys.argv) <=3:
      print >>sys.stderr, 'usage:DnsCheck <hostname> <hostname> <hostname>'
      sys.exit(2)
   args = str(sys.argv[1:])
   command = "dig " + args

   def main(args):
      try:
         for i in args:
         #socket.gethostbyname(i)
         os.popen(command)
   except socket.error, e:
      print e

   if __name__ == '__main__':
      main(args)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import socket
import sys

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print("Usage: dnscheck hostname [hostname...]")
    else:
        for host in sys.argv[1:]:
            try:
                ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)
                print("{} resolves to {}".format(host, ip))
            except socket.gaierror:
                print("Could not resolve {}".format(host))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, it erros during the: print("{} resolves to {}".format(host, ip))

Comment: Works for me (32-bit Python 2.7.2) - what version are you running, and what error message do you get? If 2.6 or previous, may have to replace the format string with "{0} resolves to {1}" to make it do the substitution properly.

Comment: Thanks, I made updated the file and the script runs correctly. Thank you.